# how to stop commited mutation in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Is there any way in `vuex` to stop a mutation after commit? For `redux`, if `next` is not called in middleware, then we can say that the action is stopped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot stop a mutation after commit.

If your application needs to prevent a commit in only certain circumstances, you could put that logic in an action:

```
mutations: {
  INCREASE_FOO(state) {
    state.foo++;
  }
},
actions: {
  increaseFoo({commit}) {
    if (someCondition) {
      commit('INCREASE_FOO');
    }
  }
}
```

Then, when dispatching the action via `this.$store.dispatch('increaseFoo')`, the commit will only fire under the specified condition.

Comment: What's to stop a mutation from performing the same check? I don't generally use Vuex. Seems like it could.

Comment: Nothing. It depends on the scenario (which I'm guessing at the OPs scenario). But I like keeping mutations as simple as I can. The check could also be around the `dispatch` call.

Comment: I guess the most Vuex-like approach is an action to keep the logic in the store. Sounds good.

Comment: Yeah and now that I think about it, mutations only have access to the state object and anything passed as a parameter. So any conditional variable would have to be passed to the mutation, which wouldn't make sense.

Comment: this makes sense to me, I just wish it was listed as a caveat under vuex's documentation.  Currently they differentiate between actions and mutations as async/sync.